# Get date of creation of image before or after uploading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using html file upload in a MVC3 , Jquery ,HTML5 application. It is working fine. Now i want to get image meta data on file select while uploading. How i can get Date of creation and Date of Modification on file select before or after uploading the image. Please suggest me any good plugin or method to get such information.

If we get  info using .net libraries  after saving image to server, it return date of uploading as date of creation. But i need date of creation on client's computer that was before uploading.

Comment: File creation/modification are not in the file metadata. Date a photo was taken, however, should be.

Comment: ok, infact mainly i need date of creation , date of modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would need some EXIF data.

There is at least one [JavaScript Library](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exif/), and there should be plenty for .net.

Comment: I think exif is not supported in JPEG 2000 , PNG and Gif

Comment: thats right, but its the nearest you can get. *some* images may have a creation date, this depends on the Partition type they are using [NTFS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299648/en-us) for example does change the "creation date" pretty often. i just remember there was a exotic type which does actually keep the orginal date.